# Solve equation with $\arccos$ and sqrt

Tags: inverse-function

I have an equation to calculate $A$ from $r$ and $h$:
$$
A= \arccos\left(\frac{r-h}{r}\right)r^2 - (r-h)\sqrt{r^2-(r-h)^2} 
$$

But now $A$ and $r$ are known, and I want to solve for $h$ instead.
So far, I solve this equation numerically, but I was wondering whether it can be solved analytically.
All three $A$, $r$ and $h$ are positive.
I have tried to solve it using Wolfram Alpha, but I only get a timeout. Any better ideas?

Comment: Well, that's essentially Kepler's equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation#Radial_Kepler_equation). 
>" I am sufficiently satisfied that it [Kepler's equation] cannot be solved a priori, on account of the different nature of the arc and the sine. But if I am mistaken, and any one shall point out the way to me, he will be in my eyes the great Apollonius."
— Johannes Kepler

Comment: Thanks, I came across this equation when reviewing code for calculating areas, the Wikipedia link has some helpful links, e.g. this one: https://www.winemantech.com/blog/the-numerical-analysis-of-finding-the-height-of-a-circular-segment